# Why is the error Expected a "}" in Hew using C

Tags: c

```
char buffer[30]; 
char Days[7] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
GetTimeOfTheDay();
```

I'm getting error at second line as Expected a "}".What can be the possible reason?any thoughts?

Comment: `char Days[7]` --> `char *Days[7]`

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that the compiler gave that particular error message. Usually when a compiler complains that it expects a particular token, it's because of a syntax error. The problem here is that the initializer elements are of the wrong type. But certainly the type error needs to be fixed.

Comment: The compiler expected a `}` because `{ "Sun" }` would have been a valid initializer for the array. So the comma was a syntax error from the compiler's point of view.

Comment: You need to define a 2D array `char Days[7][3]` or a list of pointers        `char *Days[7]`.

Comment: A 2D array would need to be `Days[7][4]` to store the `\0` character.

Answer (score 2):

```
char Days[7] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
```

can store *one* string of a maximum of 6 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator). Fix it by using a 2D array:

```
char Days[7][4] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
```

or use an array of pointers to `char` as [@BLUEPIXY suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959728/why-is-the-error-expected-a-in-hew-using-c/34959755#comment57650555_34959728):

```
char *Days[7] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
```

Note that you aren't supposed to modify the strings if you use this method.

Answer (score 1):

That might be because you've defined an array of characters and not an array of strings.  `char Days[7]` refers to an array of seven characters.

You could use `char Days[7][4]` for a multidimensional array with seven three-letter strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
char Days[7] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"}; // <--- Incorrect because the initializers are for strings not chars.
```

So use an array of pointer to char instead:

`char *Days[] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};`

Or, alternatively use a 2D character array:

`char Days[][30] = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};`

In either case, it's better to omit the number of array elements `7`. You don't need to provide the number of array elements when you already provide the list of values.